# How to change the material-ui-pickers time-picker timezone?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker, luxon

Time-picker is showing local timezone, how to change that to desired timezone?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in other answers, the Material-UI pickers use a third-party date/time library, which you need to add and configure.

So, you'll need to yarn/npm add these:

```
yarn add moment
yarn add moment-timezones
yarn add @date-io/moment@1.x moment
```

In your `App.js` add this:

```
import moment from 'moment'

let launchMoment = require('moment')
require('moment-timezone')
moment.tz.setDefault('America/Los_Angeles')
```

You can change the `setDefault` to your desired [timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/):

In the component that you're using the picker, you'll need to import these:

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers'
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment'
```

Your picker will look something like this:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
          <KeyboardDatePicker
            disableToolbar
            variant="inline"
            format="ddd MMM Do"
            margin="normal"
            id="date-picker-inline"
            value={date}
  
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
              'aria-label': 'change date'
            }}
           
          />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Note: the Pickers support other date/time libraries, but some don't have local timezone configurability, such as `date-fns`

Comment: I feel like this is the solution; however when i remove utils={DateFnsUtils} my date picker breaks. is there a way to use multiple utils?

Comment: @mark.inman This is because the picker expects different type of `value` based on the used adapter (previously `utils`). This is because it's the adapter which internally handles date operations. So if you switch from date-fns to moment, you should pass a moment object as value

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding. You provide a date to the datepicker, it only shows the passed date.
For timezone shift you have to take a look to the date provider you make use of coupled with the picker, usually one of the following:

- [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/)
- [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)
- [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Material-ui-pickers will leverage the timezone you configured for the application. If your `moment` instance is set up to use particular timezone - when you pass it to the picker component it will use that timezone and return back the date in the same timezone.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

The v6 has a [built-in timezone management](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/timezone/) for some of the libraries